# dense rank partition error mariadb

Tags: mariadb

I have a very simple query on maria 10.0.32

```
SELECT v.id, v.ver, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) AS dense_rank FROM v;
```

I receive the following error:

Check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) AS dense_rank FROM v

Comment: Maybe it's because you use a keyword (`dense_rank`)  as a column alias? Try another name.

Comment: hi thanks still does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MariaDB supports `DENSE_RANK` as of version 10.2. You are using 10.0.32, so the function is not supported in your version. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/dense_rank/